# How to add head section in a page that has layout template

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need add specific css file for my page "Index.cshtml" that has layout "_BasicLayout.cshtml".

In ASP.NET WebForms I could do it with ContentPlaceHolder like this:

Master Page:

```
<head>
    <Link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
    <ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" />
</head>
```

Child Page (Layout = Master Page):

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Head">
     <Link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="specific.css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Question:

How to do it in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Layout page put something like this:

```
@RenderSection("AdditionalStyles", required: false)
```

Then in your child pages where you want to use it, you can do:

```
@section AdditionalStyles
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/fileupload/css")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an optional [section](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) (old but accurate reference).

In the layout:

```
<head>
    @* things you always want in the head *@
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/my-main-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

    @* an optional section called "styles" *@
    @RenderSection( "styles", false )
</head>
```

In your views that need to add a stylesheet(s):

```
@section styles {
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/another-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
}
```